# Learning Regex with simple example

Tags: python

I've been reading some documentation and looking at examples. I have some unexpected behiavor and wondering if someone could help me understand what regex is doing

```
string = "(ID: 10427645)" ## the ID length can vary

c = re.findall(r"\d*", string)
print(c)
## ['', '', '', '', '', '10427645', '', '']
```

I expected it to print just the number, but it looks like its returning an empty string for each item in the string that doesn't have a match.

How do I tell regex to just return a string of numbers (of varying length)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*` means "0 or more". So it matches against all positions, whether or not there is a digit.

To only match 1 or more digits, use `+`:

```
>>> re.findall(r"\d+", string)
['10427645']
```